# What is more efficient - synchronization on a method or a block

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

Can someone please tell me whether its more efficient to `synchronize` on a method or a block in Java?

Just thinking about this, when you `synchronize` on something it affects the performance so I would assume that synchronizing on a block is preferential to synchronizing on a method as it takes up less code - is this always the case?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Seriously, i just wanted to know the answer to a question - in future i wont bother

Comment: @maloney I assume the downvotes are for not doing any research for existing questions/answers on this site.

Comment: @A.H. all the answers i could find were to do with when you would use synchronized on a method or a block - not which one was more efficient...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you synchronize the method, then the whole method is synchronized so only one thread can execute that method at a time. If you synchronize a code block within that method then more than one thread can execute the method simultaneously, but only one thread can enter the synchronized block at a time.

From this we can conclude that synchronizing on the smallest possible code block required is the most efficient way to do it. However the practical difference between synchronizing a method vs. a code block really depends on the method and what code is being left out of the synchronized block.

Comment: OP is not asking for  definition .